# Android Studio - Can't load kernel bindary, invalid SDK hash??(protoc and dart)

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, protoc

Snipit of the issue in AS

[image: Snipit of the issue in AS]

I can generate other code from proto files, but dart will not play nicely. Any thoughts? Thank you!

Comment: **from within Android Studio, can generate py and java with no issues.

Comment: ***This made the code, but I do not know if the error is telling me anything useful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is happened because the protoc binary is not from your flutter binary cache but using the other older one. It can be from dart pub cache or previous flutter pub cache installed on your system.

For Linux, you need to deactivate all the protoc plugin from your system the activate it again then use the installed protoc path.

Here the steps:

1. Deactivate protoc plugin for dart:

   ```
   $ pub global deactivate protoc_plugin
   ```
2. Deactive protoc plugin for flutter:

   ```
   $ flutter pub global deactivate protoc_plugin
   ```
3. Activate protoc plugin for flutter, this will install proto plugin to your flutter installed directory:

   ```
   $ flutter pub global activate protoc_plugin
   ```
4. For Linux, add pub cache path of your flutter installed directory to your `.bashrc`. Remember to change `/opt/flutter/` to your installed directory:

   ```
   export PATH="$PATH:/opt/flutter/.pub-cache/bin:/opt/flutter/bin"
   ```
5. Log out and login again to activate your path.

Comment: Thank you for your input, sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 1):

1. ```
   vi ~/.bash_profile
   add  export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"
   source ~/.bash_profile
   ```
2. ```
   flutter upgrade
   ```
3. ```
   brew install protobuf

   brew tap dart-lang/dart

   brew install dart
   ```

OR

```
which flutter
=> /Users/{UserName}/Applications/flutter/bin/flutter

rm /Users/{UserName}/Applications/flutter/bin/cache/flutter_tools.stamp
```

final, reopen Terminal.